# How to pass multiple parameters dynamically into Html.Action in Asp .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, parameter-passing, html-helper

I have parameters to send like

`@Html.Action("actionName", "controlName", new{ pName1 = "pValue1", ...  })`

But, `pName1 = "pValue1", ...` will come with ViewBag from a controller. What should type of object encapsulated with ViewBag, and how can I set route values into Html.Action?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to send some data stored in ViewBag in the route values?

Comment: Yes. As you understood.

Comment: do your self a favor and avoid the view bag.  the view bag is great but it is the quick and dirty answer.  I strongly recommend using a defined model object to store information from the controller to pass into the view.

@model someclass

strongly typed views are much easier to maintain than views that rely of the view bag.

Comment: @jcwmoore, what is the problem with ViewBag?

Comment: @serefbilge, I have written applications that relied on the ViewData (predecessor to ViewBag) and applications that only used models.  the latter was much cleaner and far easier to test.  There is nothing wrong with the ViewBag, I just avoid it, http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/12/stop-using-viewbag-in-most-places.html

Comment: @jcwmoore, I use ViewBag, because there is a model already used in view; and I need to send extra object other than model; and in some of these situations, combining multiple objects inside model is not logical, so sometimes I need to use viewbag.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Passing-Parameters-to-an-Action-with-Html-Action--in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of object can be anything you like from primitive types such as int, string, etc... to custom objects.

If you have assigned a value to ViewBag such as:

```cs
public class CustomType {
  public int IntVal { get; set; }
  public string StrVal { get; set; }
}
...
ViewBag.SomeObject = new CustomType { IntVal = 5, StrVal = "Hello" }
```

You can invoke it simply as:

```cs
@Html.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { myParam = @ViewBag.SomeObject })
```

And in your controller:

```cs
public ActionResult SomeAction(CustomType myParam ) {
  var intVal = myParam.IntVal;
  var strVal = myParam.StrVal;
  ...
}
```

However, note that you can still access ViewBag from within your controllers without having to pass them in route values.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: It is usable, I prefer to use it with Dictionary<string, string> type , because with string data names(keys) can be easily accessible without further definition. so one vote to you. Thanks.